# Missing Widget Material Design - Exposed Drop Down Menu

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

I am having a little issue implementing an Exposed Drop Down Menu in my menu. Almost all my other view's are from Material design and work perfectly. However, the "style" tag that the material design documentation says to implement does not exist.
https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/#exposed-dropdown-menus
According to the documentation the TextInputLayout requires a style tag of:
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdown....". This widget does not seem to exist.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.Filled"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.35"
    android:hint="@string/in1"
    android:textColorHint="@color/white">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF0000" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My App gradle build implementation:

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

The odd thing is that in my styles.xml I can actually override the needed widget, meaning that it has to have been imported...

Comment: try this: style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"

Comment: That one doesn't seem to exist either. The only sub category under these box's is "Dense"

Comment: Yes i can implement and override them, but that defeats the purpose, i shouldn't have to do that. If i override it, i won't inherit anything.

Comment: in my case, i only have as options: OutlinedBox and OutlinedBox.Dense, but if i add OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu it also works somehow

Comment: I tried just running it anyway, and i'm getting a resource not found error. AAPT: error: resource style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropDownMenu (aka com.Diagnostic.Spudnik:style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropDownMenu) not found.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
           ...>
```

This style exists in `1.1.0`. Check also the [source code](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/res/values/styles.xml#L120).

Answer (score 0):

Updating the design library to the latest one resolved the issue for me.

```
'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
```